# Prove $\log f$ is differentiable in $I$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable in $I$?

Tags: calculus

If $f\colon I\subset\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$, how can I prove that $\log f$ is differentiable in $I$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable in $I$?.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable, then $\log f=\log\circ f$, and therefore $\log f$ is differentiable.

If $\log f$ is differentiable, then $f=\exp\circ(\log f)$, and therefore $f$ is differentiable.